# Validate perl input - filter out inexistent files

Tags: perl, file, validation, parsing, input

I have a perl script to which i supply input(text file) from batch or sometimes from command prompt. When i supply input from batch file sometimes the file may not exisits. I want to catch the No such file exists error and do some other task when this error is thrown. Please find the below sample code.

```
while(<>) //here it throws an error when file doesn't exists.
{
    #parse the file.
}
#if error is thrown i want to handle that error and do some other task.
```

Answer (score 3):

Filter `@ARGV` before you use `<>`:

```
@ARGV = grep {-e $_} @ARGV;
if(scalar(@ARGV)==0) die('no files');
# now carry on, if we've got here there is something to do with files that exist
while(<>) {
  #...
}
```

`<>` reads from the files listed in @ARGV, so if we filter that before it gets there, it won't try to read non-existant files. I've added the check for the size of @ARGV because if you supply a list files which are all absent, it will wait on stdin (the flipside of using <>). This assumes that you don't want to do that.

However, if you don't want to read from stdin, `<>` is probably a bad choice; you might as well step through the list of files in `@ARGV`. If you do want the option of reading from stdin, then you need to know which mode you're in:

```
$have_files = scalar(@ARGV);
@ARGV = grep {-e $_} @ARGV;
if($have_files && scalar(grep {defined $_} @ARGV)==0) die('no files');
# now carry on, if we've got here there is something to do;
#   have files that exist or expecting stdin
while(<>) {
  #...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *diamond operator* `<>` means:

> Look at the names in `@ARGV` and treat them as files you want to open.
>   Just loop through all of them, as if they were one big file.
>   Actually, Perl uses the ARGV filehandle for this purpose
>
> If no command line arguments are given, use `STDIN` instead.

So if a file doesn't exist, Perl gives you an error message (`Can't open nonexistant_file: ...`) and continues with the next file. This is what you usually want. If this is not the case, just do it manually. Stolen from the [`perlop` page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators):

```
unshift(@ARGV, '-') unless @ARGV;
  FILE: while ($ARGV = shift) {
    open(ARGV, $ARGV);
    LINE: while (<ARGV>) {
      ...         # code for each line
    }
  }
```

The [`open` *function*](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) returns a false value when a problem is encountered. So *always* invoke `open` like

```
open my $filehandle "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
```

The `$!` contains a reason for the failure. Instead of `die`ing, we can do some other error recovery:

```
use feature qw(say);
@ARGV or @ARGV = "-"; # the - symbolizes STDIN
FILE: while (my $filename = shift @ARGV) {
    my $filehandle;
    unless (open $filehandle, "<", $filename) {
       say qq(Oh dear, I can't open "$filename". What do you wan't me to do?);
       my $tries = 5;
       do {
         say qq(Type "q" to quit, or "n" for the next file);
         my $response = <STDIN>;
         exit      if $response =~ /^q/i;
         next FILE if $response =~ /^n/i;
         say "I have no idea what that meant.";
       } while --$tries;
       say "I give up" and exit!!1;
    }
    LINE: while (my $line = <$filehandle>) {
       # do something with $line
    }
}
```